# Checking .empty? after destroy not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I wrote a test that checks for referral's from user's within the same company. In the assertions I am checking that the referrals are not empty, then running the destroy_referrals method before finally checking that the referrals are empty. `assert referrals.empty?` is returning a failure,

`1) Failure:
CompanyTest#test_destroy_referrals_with_referrals [test/models/company_test.rb:634]:
Expected false to be truthy.`

company_test.rb

```
def test_destroy_referrals_with_referrals
    company = companies(:default)
    referrals = company.users.map {|u| u.referrals unless u.referrals.empty?}.uniq.compact

    assert !referrals.empty?
    company.destroy_referrals
    assert referrals.empty?
end
```

I was expecting that the last assertion would confirm that the referrals have been deleted. Any ideas why this throws a failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referrals is an array object. You loaded it once, it stays in memory. Why would you expect it to change?

Re-read it.

```
referrals = company.users.map {|u| u.referrals unless u.referrals.empty?}.uniq.compact

assert !referrals.empty?
company.destroy_referrals

company.reload # just for good measure
referrals = company.users.map {|u| u.referrals unless u.referrals.empty?}.uniq.compact
assert referrals.empty?
```

Comment: CPDD? :) Love it.

Comment: Ah yes, it's absolutely that :) Allows me to be an insanely productive developer :)

Comment: I get it; we load an array, and because it stays in memory, we need to then reload that same array before checking if the method was executed.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have prepared the referrals in advance and never changed it. To make the test to pass, you should reload them:

```
def test_destroy_referrals_with_referrals
    company = companies(:default)
    referrals = -> { company.users.map(&:referrals).reject(&:empty?) }

    assert !referrals.().empty?
    company.destroy_referrals
    assert referrals.().empty?
end
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev damn it. Now it will :)

Comment: This is also a great answer, however, I don't want to write it as a multi-line block....not sure why but throws new errors when trying to `print` etc.